# Android Firebase retrieve child of child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase.
The name inside Info

This is my firebase tree.

[image]

I've already done this

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://link.firebaseio.com/Users/xxxxxxxx/Categories/drinks/");
```

Then I've created my listener

```
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.e("TOTAL ITEM " ,""+ dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

                    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Item_Get_List newPost = eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue(Item_Get_List.class);
                        System.out.println("GetChildren: "+eventSnapshot.child("Info"));
                        System.out.println("details: "+eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue());

                    }
```

I got this in the console:

```
E/TOTAL ITEM: 2
I/System.out: GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = Info, value = null }
I/System.out: details: null
I/System.out: GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = Info, value = null }
I/System.out: details: null
E/TOTAL ITEM: 2
I/System.out: GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = Info, value = null }
I/System.out: details: null
I/System.out: GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = Info, value = null }
I/System.out: details: null
E/TOTAL ITEM: 1
I/System.out: GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = Info, value = {name=Pierre} }
I/System.out: details: {name=Pierre}
```

But if I want to do

```
Item_Get_List newPost = eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue(Item_Get_List.class);
System.out.println("Name: "+newPost.getName());
```

I've got this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.app.pierre.myapp.Item_Get_List.getName()' on a null object reference
```

My Item_Get_list class is as follow:

```
public class Item_Get_List {
    private String name;

    public Item_Get_List(){

    }

    public Item_Get_List(String name){
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

What I have done wrong ??

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE** 
I found one temporary solution by doing

```
if(eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue() != null){
                        System.out.println("Name: "+newPost.getName());
                    }
```

But that's just temporary, because I know i'm doing something wrong here. =(

Answer (score 0):

As your data tree contains child within child **you need to execute two for loops to get in deeper layer.**

**//change this**

```
    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //Item_Get_List newPost = eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue(Item_Get_List.class); System.out.println("GetChildren: "+eventSnapshot.child("Info")); System.out.println("details: "+eventSnapshot.child("Info").getValue());
}
```

**//to this**

```
    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //
        for (DataSnapshot childEventSnapshot : eventSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Item_Get_List newPost = childEventSnapshot.child("name").getValue(Item_Get_List.class);
   System.out.println("GetChildren: "+childEventSnapshot.child("name")); System.out.println("details: "+childEventSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
    }
  }
```

Please let me know if this changes anything for you. Hopefully this will get you what you want. Do comment if something is still not right.

---

**EDIT**: I think the object null error is caused by this

```
Item_Get_List newPost = childEventSnapshot.child("name").getValue(Item_Get_List.class);
```

**Remove .child("name") and make it**

```
Item_Get_List newPost = childEventSnapshot.getValue(Item_Get_List.class);
```

Comment: I just tried, but still come the same error and also still the GetChildren: DataSnapshot { key = name, value = null } on the console.

Comment: Hey that is actually not the actual error.  Are you using this in java project or android project ?. Because if you are using in android then I wouldn't consider this an error unless your logcat shows an error. This is your custom debug check.

Comment: I'm using android but i mean i still got: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.app.pierre.myapp.Item_Get_List.getName()' on a null object reference if I add System.out.println("Name: "+newPost.getName());

Comment: Use this to check in your sysout.                String name = (string) childEventSnapsho.child("name").getValue();                                                           **Note** : you are no where checking the data from pojo because I feel it is getting saved there correctly. Use my string cast suggestion to pass this value in sysout and check that.

Comment: I have updated my answer please make that change and you should be getting value in pojo this time. **Nested for loops remain same. Just make change in way you saving data in pojo.**

Comment: There was a typo in previous string cast example. You need to do this ......      String name = (String) childEventSnapshot.child("name").getValue();                                                          now print out **name** in console. Also Update pojo data saving  as suggested in answer edit.

Comment: If I do the string cast and print out I got  E/TOTAL ITEM: 2
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null
 E/TOTAL ITEM: 1
 I/System.out: Name: Pierre
 I/System.out: Name: null
 I/System.out: Name: null so actualy 10 null field..

Comment: And if I change the newPost from your edit I got a new error: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.app.pierre.myapp.Item_Get_List] from Long integral number; no single-long-arg constructor/factory method

Comment: Your database ref is also cause of this error.. Keep the code same and change this Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://link.firebaseio.com/Users/xxxxxxxx/Categories/drinks/Item/Pierre")                                           actually your database tree is pretty deep so you need to dig deeper in ref link as well. Right now all those nulls are there coz it's setting through each child under **drinks**

Comment: You have to pass the node **Pierre** as ending node in your databse ref for the current version of code to work. Update ref according to the data snapshot you want. It will be easier to manage and retrieve

Comment: Just let you know I will go back on it tomorrow, cause it's 5am for me now.. I will let you know about.. but adding Item on my Firebase ref get me result "name" from ItemField now.. and still some null value..

Comment: Yes sure you need to go deeper than item ... Upto  **Pierre** node you can try that tomorrow and let me know the update